# Hazelcast Jet - how to use a non-static method in a Jet pipeline

Tags: lambda, hazelcast-jet

I have a basic pipeline below. In one of the steps I want to transform an object by calling a method from a service as below. But Jet throws an error saying that this `mapFn` is not serializable. What to do here? It works perfectly fine for static methods.

```java
p.readFrom(source)
     .map(r -> dataTransformer.transformRecord(r))// dataTransformer is a service
     .writeTo(Sinks.filesBuilder(userHome).build());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mapUsingService` and create the service using the `ServiceFactory`:

```java
p.readFrom(source)
 .mapUsingService(
    ServiceFactories.sharedService(pctx -> new DataTransformer()),
    (dataTransformer, r) -> dataTransformer.transformRecord(r))
 ...
```

Alternatively, if your service is serializable and stateless, you can copy it to a local variable:

```java
DataTransformer dataTransformerLocal = dataTransformer;
p.readFrom(source)
     .map(r -> dataTransformerLocal.transformRecord(r))
     .writeTo(Sinks.filesBuilder(userHome).build());
```